# Как сделать запрос в базу данных query_posts по условию?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, циклы

Есть сайт на `wordpress`, в блоке вывода постов которого есть запрос `query_posts` и стандартный цикл `while (have_posts()) : the_post();`.

```
    <?php  query_posts('showposts=6&cat=98,100,97,99'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     ...
        <?php  endwhile; ?>

    <div class="home-post-block">
        <?php echo adrotate_ad(1);?>
    </div>      
    <div class="home-post-block">
        <?php echo adrotate_ad(2);?>
    </div>
    <div class="home-post-block">
        <?php echo adrotate_ad(3);?>
    </div>  
    <?php endif; ?>
```

У меня установлен плагин баннерной рекламы `adrotate`, объявления которого я хочу выводить в этом же блоке, если они активны

```
    <div class="home-post-block">
        <?php echo adrotate_ad(2);?>
    </div>
```

Вопрос: как это правильно сделать технически? думаю, что как-то так, но что-то здесь не то...

```
<?php
$count=0;
if(adrotate_ad(1) && adrotate_ad(2) && adrotate_ad(3) { $count=3; }
else if (adrotate_ad(1) && adrotate_ad(2)) { $count=4; }
else if (adrotate_ad(2) && adrotate_ad(3)) { $count=4; }
else if (adrotate_ad(1) && adrotate_ad(3)) { $count=4; }
else if (adrotate_ad(1) || adrotate_ad(2) || adrotate_ad(3)) { $count=5; }
else { $count=6; }
query_posts('showposts=$count&cat=98,100,97,99'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему бы не посчитать в цикле сколько блоков рекламы активно

```
<?php
$adcount = 0;
for ($ix = 1; $ix < 4; $ix += 1) {
    if (adrotate_ad($ix)) $adcount += 1;
}
$count = 6 - $adcount;
query_posts('showposts=' . $count . '&cat=98,100,97,99'); 
?>
```

**Дополнено**. В связи с новыми обстоятельствами (аргумент `adrotate_ad()` - это id-блока) предлагаю следующее:

```
<?php
$adcount = 0;
$adIds = array(7, 8, 19, 20);
foreach ($adIds as $id) {
    if (adrotate_ad($id)) $adcount += 1;
}
$count = 6 - $adcount;
query_posts('showposts=' . $count . '&cat=98,100,97,99'); 
?>
```

Comment: просто на самом деле блоков рекламы больше в целом, чем я хочу выводить конкретно здесь и они располагаются вразнобой: мне нужно вывести блоки под `id` 7,8,19,20 и в дальнейшем не хотелось бы зависимости, если блоки поменяются или пополнятся с другими `id`

Comment: @Вася Эту информацию стоило давать в тексте вопроса. Обновил ответ

Comment: и все же где-то ошибка - не выводит то, что нужно. Во-первые, в запросе точно не срабатывает переменная `showposts=$count&cat=98,100,97,99`. Пытаюсь выкрутиться через серию условию, но и у меня где-то ошибка: включены 2 объявления должно выводится 4 поста+2 объявления ($count правильно показывает 4, $adcount - 2), но выводится почему-то 2 поста..

Comment: if($count==6) { query_posts('showposts=6&cat=98,100,97,99'); }
elseif ($count==5) { query_posts('showposts=5&cat=98,100,97,99'); }
elseif ($count==4) { query_posts('showposts=4&cat=98,100,97,99'); }
elseif ($count==3) { query_posts('showposts=3&cat=98,100,97,99'); }
elseif ($count==2) { query_posts('showposts=2&cat=98,100,97,99'); }

если напрямую подставить 4, то выводится 4, как и положено

Comment: @Вася Не подставляется переменная потому что вы использовали  одиночные кавычки, а я тупо скопировал запрос. Посыпаю голову пеплом. Исправил ответ

Comment: и все равно что-то не так - выводятся 2 поста и 2 объявления, хотя поста должно быть 4, в `$count` показывает 4, `$adcount` 2. Может быть в  `$count` содержится что-то лишнее и нужно принудительно его в `int` привести какому-нить?

Comment: разобрался, условие `if (adrotate_ad($id))` показывает количество всех объявлений, действующие+те, у которых срок годности прошел, отключенные